# How to subscribe to completion of RACCommand

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

```
RACSignal *s1 = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable * _Nullable(id<RACSubscriber>  _Nonnull subscriber) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
        NSLog(@"s1");
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
    });
    return nil;
}];
RACSignal *s2 = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable * _Nullable(id<RACSubscriber>  _Nonnull subscriber) {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSLog(@"s2");
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
    });
    return nil;
}];

self.command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal * _Nonnull(id  _Nullable input) {
    return [s1 then:^RACSignal * _Nonnull{
        return s2;
    }];
}];
[self.command execute:nil];
[self.command.executionSignals subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"completed");
}];
```

I found that `completed` did not excute. How to make it work?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: [self.command.executionSignals.switchToLatest subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"completed");
}];
why the completed block did not excute

Answer (score 0):

`RACCommand.executionSignals` is one signal that belongs to the RACCommand instance.

On this signal, the command will send another `RACSignal` as value for each execution of the command.

With your snippet

```
[self.command.executionSignals subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"Command was deallocated");
}];
```

you are observing the `RACSignal<RACSignal>` of the command - this signal will only complete, when the `RACSignal` is deallocated.

If you really need to observe the command, you will need to do the following:

```
[self.command.executionSignals subscribeNext:^(RACSignal *innerSignal) {
    [innerSignal subscribeCompleted:^{
        NSLog(@"One execution of the command completed");
    }];
}];
```

This `subscribeNext` will be called with each `execute` of the `RACCommand` and the `innerSignal` is the signal you want to observe.

However, if you actually want to know when a single execution is completed, you can subscribe directly to the signal thats returned from the `execute` call:

```
[[self.command execute:nil] subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"This execution of the command completed");
}];
```